# Using Amazon ECS with google container registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry

When I try to use AWS ECS with private google container registry my task always in pendings state.
According to AWS docs I add env variables in container definition

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA=
{"https://eu.gcr.io": {
    "email": "not@val.id", 
    "auth": "some hash"
  }}
```

But I get this error

```
"CannotPullContainerError: Error: image not found"
```

My full task definition

```
{
  "requiresAttributes": [],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:745964170259:task-definition/test:2",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "revision": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "memory": 128,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "hostname": null,
      "essential": true,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "name": "nginx_test",
      "ulimits": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE",
          "value": "dockercfg"
        },
        {
          "name": "ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA",
          "value": "{\"https://eu.gcr.io\":{\"auth\":\"somehash\",\"email\":\"not@val.id\"}}"
        }
      ],
      "links": null,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "image": "eu.gcr.io/project_id/image_name",
      "command": null,
      "user": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "privileged": null
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "family": "test"
}
```

What is right task definition for this case?

Answer (score 2):

The `ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE` and `ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA` environment variables should be specified for the ECS Agent, not specified in your task definition. The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html) has instructions on how to use private registries.